# Could not install package 'EnterpriseLibrary.Common 6.0.1304'

Tags: visual-studio-2015, enterprise-library, application-blocks

I am trying to install Microsoft Data Access Block in new created dll, but I am facing issue,unable to understand what exactly the issue is.. please help me anyone.The error is below:

```
Could not install package 'EnterpriseLibrary.Common 6.0.1304'.
You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', 
but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files  
that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to reference an assembly that doesn't support a Portable Class Library. I can assume that you're trying to add that reference to a Class Library (Portable) project.